# Changing the color of Ticks and FrameTicks only without changing the labels

Tags: plotting, ticks

How do I change the color of the ticks, by which I mean the short lines on the axis, without changing the style of the accompanying labels? If I use `FrameTickStyle` `TickStyle` it changes both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`FontColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontColor) rule:

```
Graphics[{}, Frame->True, FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Red, FontColor->Blue]]
```

[image]